# How to get an id in a many2many field?

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-9.1, openerp-7

Does someone can explain what is going on with my sql statement. Here is my code chunk.

```
for so in self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(cr,uid,so_id,context):
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\t SALE ORDER ID %d"%(so.id))

    confirmed_by = so.confirmed_by.id
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\tconfirmed by %s"%(str(confirmed_by)))

    rg_id = cr.execute("select rg.id from res_users ru,res_groups rg,res_groups_users_rel rgr
                            where ru.id = rgr.uid and rgr.gid = rg.id and ru.id = "+str(confirmed_by)+" and rg.name like 'Project Second User'")
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\tRES GROUPS IDS %s"%(rg_id))
```

My confirmed by returns an id but I don't know why **rg_id** returns **None** when executed. When used in PgAdmin my query works fine.

**Any help is very much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

This is how manage to solve the **None** issue:

```
cr.execute("select rg.id from res_users ru,res_groups rg,res_groups_users_rel rgr
                 where ru.id = rgr.uid and rgr.gid = rg.id and ru.id = "+str(confirmed_by)+" and rg.name like 'Project Second User'")
rg_id = cr.fetchall()
```

Now, my **rg_id** is returning either an **id** from a table res_groups or **[]** if there is no record found.